# how to calculate the percentage ratio of two columns in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which is supposed to return the number of passed and failed activities.

I'm stock at calculating the percentage ratio between the failed and passed activities for each row, as you can see right now I am returning 0.

any help is much appreciated.

query:

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
    select activityid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN success = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN success = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
    from mytable
    group by activityid
)
select activityid, pass, fail,
0 as passPercentage, 0 failPercentage
from cte
```

resultset:

```
activityid  pass    fail    passPercentage   failPercentage
1            26      22      0                    0
2            23      29      0                    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
    select activityid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN success = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN success = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
    from mytable
    group by activityid
)
select activityid, pass, fail,
 pass*100.0/(pass + fail) as passPercentage,
 fail*100.0/(pass + fail) as failPercentage
from cte
```

**UPDATE**

In case f you have empty activities.

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
    select activityid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN success = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN success = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
    from mytable
    group by activityid
)
select activityid, pass, fail,
 CASE WHEN pass + fail = 0 THEN 0 ELSE pass*100.0/(pass + fail) END as passPercentage,
 CASE WHEN pass + fail = 0 THEN 0 ELSE fail*100.0/(pass + fail) END as failPercentage
from cte
```

Comment: hi, how can I make sure its full proof against divide by zero ?

Comment: @xerxes Divide by zero should never happen, the sum will always return at least one either pass or fail, otherwise the activity won't be in this table.

Comment: @TomasPastircak, Yes, but what if the provided query is simplified version? In the real world it can happen of course.